# make -j4 error opencv on kali linux

Tags: linux

When I execute the command "make -j4", then it doesn't work. 
Below is the output that I am getting. How can I fix this problem?

```
/usr/include/c++/6/cstdlib:75:25: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
 #include_next <stdlib.h>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
modules/viz/CMakeFiles/pch_Generate_opencv_viz.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'modules/viz/precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_viz_Release.gch' failed
make[2]: *** [modules/viz/precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_viz_Release.gch] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3227: recipe for target 'modules/viz/CMakeFiles/pch_Generate_opencv_viz.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/viz/CMakeFiles/pch_Generate_opencv_viz.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 16%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_video
[ 16%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_video
[ 16%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_perf_video
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Unless your code is explicitly set up for parallel compilation -- why would you expect that it would work? Code must be compiled in order unless explicitly designed otherwise.

Comment: Maybe try clearing out your build directory and re-running `cmake`. Failing that, try running `cmake` with `-DENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF`